Google oAuth2 "Authorisation required" error
I'm getting an authentication error while trying to authenticate with my e-mail. I think maybe my code is failing to create the "token.json" file. I tried doing explicit logging to understand the error better but I have no clue where my code is going wrong. I'm getting the error message "Token not found, requiring authentication" someone help
function authorizeGoogle(callback) {
  const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = googleCredentials;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Token not found, requiring authentication');
      return callback(oAuth2Client);
    }
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(null, oAuth2Client);
  });
}

